# MIPS - Assembly count goes down but goes into infinite loop

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to count down from a number that is inputted by the user and want to display all of the integers in between the number and 0. My Output I believe goes down, but then it goes into an infinite loop at 1. It seems to never get to zero.

I just started learning assembly so I'll apologize in advance if this is a bad question.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
.globl  main

.data
    msg: .asciiz "Input a number: "
    x: .word 1

    .text
main:

    li  $v0,4       # display the first message
    la  $a0, msg
    syscall 

    li  $v0, 5      # call for an input read, stores in $v0
    syscall

    move    $t0, $v0    # move the input to a temporary register
    lw  $t1, x          # loads x into $t1 registers

# Show Output
doLoop:
    sub $v0, $t0, $t1   # subtracts 1 from given input stores in $v0

    move $s0, $v0

    li $v0, 1       # Prepares to print integer
    move $a0, $v0
    syscall

    bgt $a0, 0, doLoop

    li  $v0,10      # load the "exit" number into register $v0
    syscall
```

Comment: google "mips debugging" and throw in the simulator you use (MARS or SPIM?). Then watch yourself, how the values in registers evolve and why your loop test doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using MARS, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick for me, I keep screwing up where I was putting constants in my registers. Therefore every time I tried to print the register contained a 1.

```
doLoop: 

sub     $t2, $t0, $t1   # subtracts 1 from given input stores in $v0

li  $v0, 1      
move    $a0, $t2    # Places answer in $a0
la  $v0, 1
syscall

move    $t0, $t2    
bgt $a0, 0, doLoop

li  $v0,10      # load the "exit" number into register $v0
syscall
```

Comment: What is purpose of `la  $t3, 1`? And you don't need three temporary registers, you can keep the main counter value in single register, and use immediate for subtraction (with `addi`). And in your answer the `bgt` is still testing against `a0`, which works only because `syscall` didn't modify it.

Comment: In what circumstance would syscall modify it? Also can I use $v0, 1 instead of doing another temporary?

Comment: It should be documented somewhere which registers are clobbered by `syscall` and which are guaranteed to be preserved.  This is an important part of a system-call calling convention, just like for a function-call calling convention.  (Note that the convention depends on software, so you need an answer specific to the MARS `syscall` API/ABI, and that might be different from Linux MIPS `syscall`.)

Comment: In what circumstances - in any when it will. The registers of CPU are sort of "super-globals", i.e. there is only one `$2` (`$v0` alias) register in the CPU. So when you give control to some different piece of code, it will use "your" registers too. If the `syscall` would decide to modify `$v0`, upon return you would see the new value. To avoid storing/restoring all registers to memory (slow) each time before every call of subroutine, the programmers of target platform have [calling convention](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse410/09sp/examples/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf).

Comment: So if you will keep your "counter" value in `$s0`, the syscall should never modify it (unless its code has bug). OTOH you should first store original `s0` to memory, and restore before exit, to be super-correct (doesn't matter in this case for `main` body of your code in MARS, you can modify `s0` without any ill effect upon exit). One problem is, that the MARS/SPIM are simulators, not actual machines, so they are sort of "softer" on the coder, making the situation easier than on real machine, for example all syscalls are super fast, and modify minimal amount of registers. Forgiving some bugs.

Comment: I understand how it will forgive some bugs, so you are saying the way I'm storing variables and interacting is incorrect? I guess I'm sort of confused this gives me my desired outputs, I just don't understand what is wrong with it. @ped7g

Comment: Yes, correct outputs with any complex assembly program usually means you are lucky enough to not hit any major bug in your code. Judging correctness of assembly source by outputs is meaningless, there may be very subtle mistakes which will demonstrate only with certain input values, or only when the code is reused in slightly different way, uncovering some deficiency. If you are writing routine, which should be easily callable by somebody else, you should conform to the calling convention, i.e. not to modify `s0-7` regs (or when you need them yourself, store original values into stack), etc...

Comment: @C2H50H: To properly assess correctness of assembly code you should go through it several times in debugger instruction by instruction, with different inputs, reasoning about each instruction whether it does what was planned, without any unforeseen side effect. That should uncover for example things like `la $t3,1` as that has no purpose for the original algorithm, and similar (although that `la` doesn't have any ill effect either). You should catch all unplanned under/overflow situations, zero/empty input, buffer indexing going out of bounds, damaged stack, etc.

Comment: And you are using those `tX` registers to hold values even when `syscall` is not obliged to preserve their content, so if the simulator will change the syscall implementation in the future, and it will start to use one of those `t` registers, your code will stop to work on such version of simulator. So even when it works in debugger for several inputs in current version, if you don't adhere to the rules, you only know it will work with particular versions of simulator, but can be broken by future updates/changes. Well written code will work as long as rules themselves don't change.